# Sending requests in parallel - passing bigger data into async worker functions

Tags: php, asynchronous, parallel-processing

I need to send a few requests where I'm sending `file_get_contents()` output in each of them. Since they take a few seconds, and execute synchronously, it takes a long time to finish. I was thinking to use some library to make it concurrent/parallel, I found [spatie/async](https://github.com/spatie/async) installable by composer:

```
$pool = Pool::create();

$image = @file_get_content("http://cdn-link.com/img.jpg");

$pool[] = async(function () use ($image) {
    return $request->send();
})->then(function ($response) {
    $this->response = $response;
});

$pool[] = async(function () use ($image) {
    return $differentRequest->send();
})->then(function ($response) {
    $this->differentResponse = $response;
});

await($pool);
```

The problem however is that if the `$image` variable is too big (usually if image is bigger than 100kb), I'm getting serialize errors due to passing it through the `use` statement. It's the same issue when I try to do it through the `$this` object. Is there a way to pass data like this to async workers? Or maybe, is there a better way to make such operations parallel?

Comment: Have you considered using streams? This will not read all data in-memory until it's needed

Comment: Why not read the file contents inside async functions?